# Wilson Loops in Principal Bundle Language

Tags: principal-bundles, quantum-field-theory

I'm currently reading [Schwartz's book](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/) and at page 489 he defines the Wilson Line field and writes in closed-form given by
$$ W_P(x,y)=\exp\left(ie \int\limits^x_y A_\mu(z) dz^\mu\right) $$

I'm looking for some reference that describes it (and related things like Wilson Loops) in a principal bundle language, with more details than the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_loop) provides.

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: In the book "Mathematical Gauge Theory" by Mark J.D. Hamilton Wilson Lines are discussed in Chapter 5.10 and 5.11.

Answer (score 0):

I think the book
"Differential Geometry and Mathematical Physics: Part II. Fibre Bundles, Topology and Gauge Fields"
is a very clear reference for these topics.